# How to track clicks of a button?

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener, tracking, event-listener

I’m trying to track the clicks on a button on my website. I’ve tried adding the following but to no success. I’m a noob to JS..

```
function trackButton(e) {
    onPage.innerHTML = ++i;
}

var i = 0;
var onPage = document.getElementById(‘track’);
var clickCount = document.getElementById(‘bttn’);
clickCount.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    addOne(e);
}, false);
```

Comment: Try replacing `addOne(e)` with `trackButton(e)`

Comment: Fix your single quotes.... `‘` and `’` will not work in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You did some mistake:

1. The function addOne doesn't exist, it's trackbutton
2. it's i++ to increment a value, not ++i

And some tips for you:

1. Use let and const (ES6) for the variable, not var
2. And the e for the event is useless here, you are not using it, so it's not mandatory here

Do these change and it must work !

**UPDATE:**

1. To increment a value ++i works, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description)
2. Change the quotes **‘‘** with **" "** or **' '**. 
   Like so: `document.getElementById(‘track‘)` to `document.getElementById('track')`

Comment: `++i` works and is probably what the original poster intended. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description).

Answer (score 0):

I was checkin your code and its almost all right, i think that the problem its in your addOne function, here is a way to resolve the problem.
i creat the button and paragraph elements in html and in javascript a variable n where we are going to storage the clicks tha the user did and we increment n when the function its called in the button's event

```js
var n = 0;
var button = document.getElementById('track');
button.addEventListener('click', trakeo);

var texto = document.getElementById('number');

function trakeo(){
  n++
  texto.innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="track">Button</button>
  <p id="number"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use
addEventListener('click',)
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp